# What does meant AC corona? Any connection to coronavirus?

Tags: terminology, soft-question, plasma-physics, biology

In the abstract of [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6463/aa84f0/meta) Authors said in abstract of that paper entitled **Simulation of the AC corona phenomenon with experimental validation** :

".....,This phenomenon is also associated with components used in the power industry where it is, in many cases, the source of electro-magnetic disturbance, noise and **production of undesired chemically active species**" , Now my question here is : Is there any connection between this topic AC Corona and Corona virus since AC corona produce undesired chemically active species ? In my Guess according to the contenent of the titled paper this Coronaviruse is a human production not come randomly from nature ?

**Edit:**  What they meant by  production of undesired chemically active species ? Does this meant from AC corona we may produce undesired chemically species which means a such virus derived from AC coron ?

Comment: I would advise looking up definitions of the word corona, the sun has a corona too which is visible during a solar eclipse. Here species is not referring to a living thing. AC coronae have no relation to the virus.

Comment: FWIW, "Corona" is from the Latin word meaning "crown." It's used in the names of things that once reminded somebody, somewhere of a crown. E.g., somebody once was reminded of a crown by the shadow of a certain virus particle in a transmission electron micrograph, and so that virus and all of its uncles and cousins now are known as "corona viruses."

Comment: "AC corona" and "coronavirus" are connected in the same way as they are to [Corona Extra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_(beer))

Comment: You would do better to learn some of the basic physics than to dive into complex material first.  It will be less frustrating for you in the long run.  As a guideline, if you (or any beginners) does not understand the wording of an abstract, the material is likely too advanced for you and you need to study more for it to be useful to you (or even to find out if it's relevant to what you want to know).  Start with the basics, please.  And I use the same guideline for myself, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

"Corona" is Latin for "crown." It is used the names of many unrelated objects.

A "corona virus" has a layer of spiky proteins around its surface, so it looks like a crown under an electron microscope.

An [electrical coronal discharge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge) happens when the electric field near an object is high enough to ionize the air; it makes a spiky glow that looks kind of like a crown. The ionized air molecules can participate in chemical reactions that aren't available to neutral air molecules, and that chemistry is a factor in the aging of high-voltage electrical systems.

In your abstract they write that most modeling of coronal discharges are of direct-current discharges, while they focus on alternating- current (AC) discharges.  For an example of the difference between anode and cathode chemistry, see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350827/44126).

Answer (score 3):

There is no connection at all between the coronavirus and the production of glow discharge in air at atmospheric pressure, which is coincidentally called "corona".

Comment: What they meant by  production of undesired chemically active species ? Does this meant from AC corona we may produce undesired chemically species which means a such virus derived from AC coron ?

Comment: @zeraoulia "species" in this context means "type of atom or ion", not a type of living thing.